# FPDF Image Error: Unsupported image type: tif

Tags: fpdf

I need solution for this error:

```
File Type Not Supported! FPDF error: Unsupported image type: tif
```

I have uploaded an image with type tiff ( image/tiff ) but I receive this error. Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

[FPDF.org](http://www.fpdf.org) says: Image support (JPEG, PNG and GIF).

Also if you want to convert a .TIFF to a .JPEG using PHP you need to install & use [ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973719/how-to-convert-tiff-to-png-jpg-bmp-in-php)